# Canvas utilities for Silverlight 2

Tags: canvas, silverlight-2.0

To save me writing the code, does anyone know of a source for utility code for working with Silverlight canvases? I am thinking of code that determines bounding boxes for content, content within clipped bounds, easy access to Transforms etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the lack of response this is either not something other people have to do that often, or there isn't really anything available that fits the bill. I have bitten the bullet and have started writing my own set of extension methods for the Canvas class starting with GetContentBounds to iterate a canvas' children and return a bounding Rect of the contents' bounding rectangle.